# How to implement MediaPlayer onErrorListener in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm trying to implement a setOnErrorListener in a videoView using Kotlin.

I found this in android developer site https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

I get stucked here:

```
vv!!.setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
        mediaPlayer, i, i2 -> true
        // how to restart the player here?!
    })
```

The complete code:

```
mediacontroller = MediaController(this)
    mediacontroller!!.setAnchorView(vv)
    val uriPath = "" //update package name
    uri = Uri.parse(uriPath)
    vv!!.setMediaController(mediacontroller)
    vv!!.setVideoURI(uri)
    vv!!.requestFocus()
    vv!!.start()

    vv!!.setOnCompletionListener {

    }

    vv!!.setOnPreparedListener {

    }

    vv!!.setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
        mediaPlayer, i, i2 -> true

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are so close

```
    vv!!.setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
        mediaPlayer, i, i2 -> 
        // mediaPlayer is refer to your MediaPlayer instance.
        //You should restart it in here.
        true
        // how to restart the player here?!
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it by my self:

```
vv!!.setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
        mediaPlayer, i, i2 -> 
        vv!!.start()
        true
    })
```